# "Object literal may only specify known properties" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tsx

I downloaded the code from this Codesandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cover-image-bf6282?from-embed=&file=/src/Card.tsx

Then I created an `.eslintrc` file with the following code (this the only code):

```
{
  "extends": "react-app"
}
```

And I'm getting this TypeScript compiling error:

[image]

What could be the problem, and how to fix it?

This is the file in question:

Card.tsx:

```
interface CardProps {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

export default function Card({ width = 660, height = 300 }: CardProps) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        height,
        width,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column",
        backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to bottom, #dbf4ff, #fff1f1)",
        fontSize: width / 12,
        letterSpacing: -width / 220,
        fontWeight: 700,
        whiteSpace: "nowrap"
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          padding: "5px 40px",
          width: "auto",
          textAlign: "center",
          backgroundImage:
            "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(0, 124, 240), rgb(0, 223, 216))",
          backgroundClip: "text",
          "-webkit-background-clip": "text",
          color: "transparent"
        }}
      >
        Build images
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          padding: "5px 40px",
          width: "auto",
          textAlign: "center",
          backgroundImage:
            "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(121, 40, 202), rgb(255, 0, 128))",
          backgroundClip: "text",
          "-webkit-background-clip": "text",
          color: "transparent"
        }}
      >
        with React
      </div>
      <div
        style={{
          padding: "5px 40px",
          width: "auto",
          textAlign: "center",
          backgroundImage:
            "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(255, 77, 77), rgb(249, 203, 40))",
          backgroundClip: "text",
          "-webkit-background-clip": "text",
          color: "transparent"
        }}
      >
        from your Browser
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @starball Sorry, what's a "stack trace"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What could be the problem, and how to fix it?

`inline` styles (webkits too) in react have to be *camelcase'd*. Replace

```
"-webkit-background-clip": "text",
```

with

```
WebkitBackgroundClip: "text",
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cover-image-forked-te5srw?file=/src/Card.tsx